# proving limit evaluates to 0 / infinity

Tags: limits

I have the following limit..

let $f(n) = e^n$
let $g(n) = n2^n$

I have to evaluate $\lim f(n)/g(n)$. My first instinct was to use L'Hospital's rule. $f'(n)$ is just $e^n$, but $g'(n) = n2^n(n\log(2)+1)$

So my argument is that since as we keep applying L'Hospital's rule, the top stays constant whereas the bottom grows logarithmically, so the limit evaluates to zero. But I don't think that's correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{e^n}{n2^n} = \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^n
\end{align*}
Observing that $\alpha\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\frac{e}{2} > 1$, what can you say about $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{n}$?

Comment: got it, thanks! seems like this evalutes to infinity

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** (really, the entire solution)

$$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{e^n}{n2^n} = \frac{\left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^n}{n}$$